# ImportError: No module named path

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I have this line in my script:

```
from path import Path
```

but I ran into this error

```
ImportError: No module named path
```

however, I have install path.py in my system, there is no problem when I write in python3 with `from path import Path` in terminal. this is very weird.

Comment: What does `sys.version` return?

Comment: '3.6.4rc1 (v3.6.4rc1:3398dcb14f, Dec  5 2017, 00:58:30) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]'

Answer (score 5):

If you mean `Path` in standard library, use [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path), not `path.Path`.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path
<class 'pathlib.Path'>
```

Comment: it's weird when I type in python3 in terminal and it's ok, but when i run the script then there is an error.

Comment: @仲耀晖 What do you get if you type `import path; print(path)` in python interactive shell?

Comment: @仲耀晖 I suspect there's  a file named `path.py` which is reside in the same directory where you launch interactive shell (terminal). `path.py` is not a part of standard library.

Comment: >>> import path
>>> print(path)
<module 'path' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/path.py'>

Comment: there is no file named path.py

Comment: @仲耀晖 Try  `import sys; print(sys.executable)` both in interactive shell , and in the script. Are outputs same?

Comment: @仲耀晖, Yes there is! `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/pytho‌​n3.6/site-packages/p‌​ath.py` ;)

Comment: @仲耀晖 If outputs are different, then you're using two different python interpreter that does not share third-party libraries. (.../site-packages/...); Use same one!

Comment: >>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: @仲耀晖, In script?

Comment: how could I use the same one? I run the script like {python3 script.py}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161548/discussion-between-falsetru-and-).

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

```
sudo pip install path.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, also

```
from os import path
```

works.